# The KTOR server refuses my plugin's register request Solved

Tags: java, httprequest, ktor, spigot

I am making a KTOR server that aims to allow the player to buy/sell IG items for money in game item. To do this, the person must be able to connect/register to the site. But, as I'm using the Minecraft nickname to facilitate the item give, it's imperative that the player registers via the Minecraft server. However, when I send my request, I get an error telling me that the response from the KTOR server is empty (the body, to be precise). I've run some tests and it turns out that the server doesn't do anything when I send the request. You can also see that when the KTOR server receives the request, it can't convert the JOIN into the desired object. I wanted to check whether the problem came from the JSON with postman, but the server responded and executed my request. So here's my error message, my register method and the log of the KTOR server when it receives my request and [here](https://github.com/LouisDufourd/Boutique)'s my KTOR server on GitHub.

Error:

```
[08:54:25] [Server thread/WARN]: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "fr.plaglefleau.inventorytojson.models.ClientRegisterReceive.isRegister()" because "clientRegisterReceive" is null
[08:54:25] [Server thread/WARN]:        at fr.plaglefleau.inventorytojson.listeners.ConnectListener$2.run(ConnectListener.java:214)
[08:54:25] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R1.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:82)
[08:54:25] [Server thread/WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_20_R1.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:415)
[08:54:25] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:1257)
[08:54:25] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:388)
[08:54:25] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1198)
[08:54:25] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1015)
[08:54:25] [Server thread/WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:304)
[08:54:25] [Server thread/WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Java class:

```
public void register(Player player, String message) {
        String[] register = message.replace(">","").replace("<","").split(";");
        String json = new Gson().toJson(
                new Register(
                        player.getName(),
                        register[0],
                        register[1]
                )
        );
        System.out.println(ConsoleColor.YELLOW + json + ConsoleColor.RESET);
        new BukkitRunnable() {
            public void run() {
                URI uri = URI.create("http://127.0.0.1/api/client/register");
                HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
                HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri)
                        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(json))
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token.TOKEN)
                        .build();
                try {
                    //send and get the response
                    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
                    System.out.println(ConsoleColor.YELLOW + response.body() + ConsoleColor.RESET);
                    if(response.body().isBlank()) {
                        System.out.println(ConsoleColor.YELLOW + "The body is Blank" + ConsoleColor.RESET);
                    }
                    ClientRegisterReceive clientRegisterReceive = new Gson().fromJson(response.body(), ClientRegisterReceive.class);
                    if(clientRegisterReceive.isRegister()) {
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + clientRegisterReceive.getMessage() + "\nWelcome " + player.getName() + ChatColor.RESET);
                        registerPlayers.remove(player.getUniqueId());
                        players.remove(player.getUniqueId());
                    } else {
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + clientRegisterReceive.getMessage() + ChatColor.RESET);
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "Please type your password and email like this : <password>;<email>" + ChatColor.RESET);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.runTask(this.plugin);
    }
```

Ktor Log:

```
2023-07-09 09:07:52.911 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.server.sessions.Sessions - Sessions found for /api/client/register: connect
2023-07-09 09:07:52.966 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.routing.Routing - Trace for [api, client, register]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /(method:GET), segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(method:GET)
    /connect, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /connect
    /register, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /register
    /(authenticate user-session), segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /(authenticate user-session)
      /(authenticate user-session)/profile, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/profile
      /(authenticate user-session)/stores, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/stores
      /(authenticate user-session)/editUser, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/editUser
      /(authenticate user-session)/editSalary, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/editSalary
      /(authenticate user-session)/editMember, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/editMember
      /(authenticate user-session)/editStock, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/editStock
      /(authenticate user-session)/bailoutStock, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/bailoutStock
      /(authenticate user-session)/addStock, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/addStock
      /(authenticate user-session)/ajouterUnMembre, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/ajouterUnMembre
      /(authenticate user-session)/createShop, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/createShop
      /(authenticate user-session)/removeMember, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/removeMember
      /(authenticate user-session)/disconnect, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate user-session)/disconnect
  /assets, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /assets
  /(authenticate api-bearer), segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /(authenticate api-bearer)
    /(authenticate api-bearer)/api, segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api
      /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/, segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/
        /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client, segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client
          /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/, segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/
            /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/connect, segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/connect
            /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/inventory, segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/inventory
            /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/register, segment:3 -> SUCCESS @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/register
              /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/register/(method:POST), segment:3 -> SUCCESS @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/register/(method:POST)
            /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/debit, segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/debit
            /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/credit, segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/credit
            /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/pay, segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/pay
            /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/updateInventory, segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/updateInventory
        /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/store, segment:1 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/store
Matched routes:
  "" -> "(authenticate api-bearer)" -> "api" -> "<slash>" -> "client" -> "<slash>" -> "register" -> "(method:POST)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS @ /(authenticate api-bearer)/api/client/register/(method:POST)
2023-07-09 09:07:52.985 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.server.auth.Authentication - Trying to authenticate /api/client/register with api-bearer
2023-07-09 09:07:53.008 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.server.auth.Authentication - Authentication succeeded for /api/client/register with provider io.ktor.server.auth.BearerAuthenticationProvider@5adad75b
2023-07-09 09:07:53.084 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE i.k.server.engine.DefaultTransform - No Default Transformations found for class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel and expected type TypeInfo(type=class fr.plaglefleau.models.api.client.receive.RegisterReceive, reifiedType=class fr.plaglefleau.models.api.client.receive.RegisterReceive, kotlinType=fr.plaglefleau.models.api.client.receive.RegisterReceive) for call /api/client/register
2023-07-09 09:07:53.121 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation - Skipping content converter for request type class fr.plaglefleau.models.api.client.receive.RegisterReceive because content type */* does not match application/json
2023-07-09 09:07:53.121 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation - No suitable content converter found for request type class fr.plaglefleau.models.api.client.receive.RegisterReceive
2023-07-09 09:07:53.138 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.server.sessions.Sessions - Sending session data for /api/client/register: connect
2023-07-09 09:07:53.141 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation - Skipping response body transformation from HttpStatusCode to OutgoingContent for the POST /api/client/register request because the HttpStatusCode type is ignored. See [ContentNegotiationConfig::ignoreType].
```

Here is my JSON in postman and in my plugin.

```json
{
    "username":"PlagLeFleau",
    "password":"PlagLeFleau0745",
    "email":"louisdufourd@gmail.com"
}
```

I found were the problème is it's simple i just don't tell the server that my request content is a json so with HttpRequest i should create my request like this

```java
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri)
                        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(json))
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token.TOKEN)
                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .build();
```

Comment: What's the status of the response?

Comment: the respond status is 415 and that what he said in the log i think because he say he could'nt convert the json to the class